# Perform docker official guide still getting error of stage -Build with Docker -7.Test

Tags: docker, go, yaml, dockerfile

Trying to self learn Docker

Following the guides
but on stage `Test` getting same error while document explain,

even after adjusted `Dockerfile` still getting same error,

copied exactly the official code and failed.

Hopefully just wrong operation on myself but not the docs.

---

Following error message suppose only comes out before the arguments,

some how it still appear after the arguments was added.

`The arguments`

```
+ ARG GOLANGCI_LINT_VERSION=v1.52
+
+ FROM golangci/golangci-lint:${GOLANGCI_LINT_VERSION} as lint
+ WORKDIR /test
+ RUN --mount=type=bind,target=. \
+     golangci-lint run
```

`The Error message`

```
 => ERROR [lint 3/3] RUN --mount=type=bind,target=.     golangci-lint run     27.7s
------                                                                              
 > [lint 3/3] RUN --mount=type=bind,target=.     golangci-lint run:                 
#0 27.37 cmd/server/main.go:23:10: Error return value of `w.Write` is not checked (errcheck)                                                                            
#0 27.37                w.Write([]byte(translated))
#0 27.37                       ^
------
Dockerfile:37
--------------------
  36 |     WORKDIR /test
  37 | >>> RUN --mount=type=bind,target=. \
  38 | >>>     golangci-lint run
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c golangci-lint run" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Tried some error print code in Golang as:

```
if _, err := w.Write([]byte(translated)); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

It only return `Line 7` at the first code block,

Output `Dockerfile:37` which indicate

`RUN --mount=type=bind,target=. \` in `Dockerfile`

---

Does the official documentation just to tell user this just a error?

or is it actually something wrong with the code?

I'm so confused

Comment: `ENV` returns `ERROR: failed to solve: no build stage in current context`, I'm gonna accept this section actually just an official error demonstration

Comment: I have posted an answer below, and I have read the question multiple times, but I still don't understand what is your question. Can you clean up the question and describe what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

This error means that `golangci-lint run` found an issue in the source code:

```
 > [lint 3/3] RUN --mount=type=bind,target=.     golangci-lint run:                 
#0 27.37 cmd/server/main.go:23:10: Error return value of `w.Write` is not checked (errcheck)                                                                            
#0 27.37                w.Write([]byte(translated))
#0 27.37                       ^
```

And your change to the source code:

```golang
if _, err := w.Write([]byte(translated)); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

should make `golangci-lint` happy. Doc for [the errcheck linter](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/linters/):

> `errcheck` is a program for checking for unchecked errors in Go code. These unchecked errors can be critical bugs in some cases.

If you want to run `golangci-lint` in a docker container, you don't need a Dockerfile. You can simply do it like this:

```
$ docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app golangci/golangci-lint: golangci-lint run -v
```

See more information and examples on the [the official doc](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/install/#docker).

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same confusion while learning from the official documentation. I resolved my confusion through a deeper understanding of the `RUN` command.

The reason for the error is that the following `RUN` command failed:

```
RUN golangci-lint run
```

This is because the exit code of `golangci-lint run` is not 0 but 1. You can use a pipeline command to make the `RUN` command execution successful, in order to complete the image build:

```
RUN golangci-lint run | cat
```

Now, as long as the exit code of the `cat` command after the pipeline operator is 0, the entire `RUN` command will execute successfully, and the image build will also succeed.